# Random string in a given interval

Tags: c, string, random

I want to create a function with this signature

```
char *generateString(char *par1, char *par2);
```

The result should be a string that is strictly greater than the `par1` (compared with `strcmp`) and strictly lower than `par2`. Par1 and par2 have random length between 0 and MAX.

Each char is choosen between `[INF,SUP]` interval. (Parameters are strings made of these characters).

String length is limited but also random between 0 and a certain MAX value.

It seems very hard to code, anyone can help?

Comment: What should happen when par1 and par2 are the same string?

Comment: It can return an empty string

Comment: so empty string if the arguments aren't valid?

Comment: Yes, it can be empty

Comment: I have found a solution and will post it soon. I am testing. As you said, it seemed and was actually very hard!

Answer (score -1):

The question asked for a random string in an exclusive range. The solution below gives a random string in an inclusive range. Solving for an inclusive range turned out to be much easier. If we want an exclusive range, we simply reject the generated string if it falls on the boundary of the range, and generate another random string until is not on the boundary of the range. I added the function `randstrx()` for this.

To illustrate my solution, we consider strings of decimal digits, that is, whose characters are in the range `C = [0 9]`. For example, `00127`, `66501`, `23`, `1`, etc. of arbitrary length. Consider all strings of a given length, for example `4`. Clearly an order exists on these strings. For example, for our strings of decimal digits, strings of length `4` are ordered as follows: `0000`, `0001`, `0002`, ..., `9999`.

Given any string of a given length, it is easy to compute the string of the same length that is immediately after or before in the string order (we ignore the two boundary cases where there is no after or before string since we will not need them). For our strings of decimal digits, we simply add or subtract `1`. Addition and subtraction are well defined in any base, and numbers may consist of any symbols, they do not have to be decimal digits. So, this defines how to add or subtract `1` (or one unit) to any string of a given length. We will use this below.

Let `S1` and `S2` be respectively the inclusive lower and upper bounds of the range of strings. We have `S1 <= S2`; order being defined by `strcmp()`. `L1` is the length of `S1`, and `L2` is the length of `S2`. We want to generate a random string `S` in the range `[S1 S2]`. `S` can be of any length `L <= M`, where `M` is a given constant. All strings contain characters in the range `C = [C1 C2]`.

**[Step 1]** The first step consists of generating a random length `L` for `S`. Depending of the values of `S1` and `S2`, not all lengths are possible. Indeed, `S1` and `S2` can start with the same sequence of characters, for example in `[123555 1237]`, `S1` and `S2` both start with `123`. Suppose that `Sk` of length `K >= 0` is the sequence of equal characters at the start of `S1` and `S2`. Let `S1 = Sk + T1` and `S2 = Sk + T2` where `T1` and `T2` are the sequences of characters following `Sk` in `S1` and `S2` respectively, and `+` is the string concatenation operator. Let `N1 >= 0` and `N2 >= 0` be the lengths of `T1` and `T2` respectively. We consider 4 cases:

- **`N1 = 0` and `N2 = 0`.** In this case, `S1 = S2 = Sk`, and so the range `[S1 S2]` contains a single string `Sk` of length `K`. So, `L = K` is the only possible value for `L`.
- **`N1 > 0` and `N2 = 0`.** This case is not possible because we assume that `S1 <= S2`.
- **`N1 = 0` and `N2 > 0`.** Clearly, `L` must be at least `K` the length of the common sequence of characters of `S1` and `S2`. To determine the upper bound of `L`, we need to consider `T2`. If `T2` can be decremented, this means we can generate strings of arbitrary length that are smaller than `S2`. For example, if `S1 = 123` and `S2 = 123001`, `12300099...9` is less than `S2` (and `> S1`). The only case where `T2` cannot be decremented is when `T2 = C1 + C1 + ... + C1`. For example, if `S1 = 123` and `S2 = 123000`, `T2` cannot be decremented. It is not possible to generate a string less than `S2` and whose length is greater than `L2`. So in this case, `L` must be in the range `[K L2]`.
- **`N1 > 0` and `N2 > 0`.** Consider the upper bound on `L`. We know that `T1 < T2` and that the first characters of `T1` and `T2` are not equal, if they were, that common first character would be in the common starting sequence `Sk`. This implies that `T1` can be incremented or that `T2` can be decremented. Indeed, for example, in our strings of decimal digits, the only `T1` that cannot be incremented is `99...9`. If `T1` were equal to this value, this would also have to be the value of `T2` but then `T1` would be equal to `T2`, and `T1` and `T2` would have to be in `Sk`, a contradiction. A similar reasoning can be done for `T2`. The only `T2` that cannot be decremented is `T2 = 00...0`, and so `T1` would also have to be `00...0` which would put `T1` and `T2` in `Sk`, a contradiction. Because `T1` can be incremented and `T2` can be decremented, we can generate random strings or arbitrary length greater than `T1` and smaller of `T2`. For example, if `S1 = 1231` and `S2 = 1234`, the strings `12311...1` and `123399...9` fall in the range `[S1 S2]`. Consider the lower bound on `L`. Any string of length `K` would have to be equal to `Sk` but since `N1 > 0`, `Sk` is less than `S1`. So the random string cannot be of length `K`. However, it is easy to show that it can be of length `K + 1`. We know that the first character `T1[0]` of `T1` is less than the first character of `T2`, and that it can be incremented. So, the string `Sk` appended with the character `T1[0] + 1` is a string of length `K + 1`, that is greater than `S1`. It is also less than or equal to `S2`. Indeed, if `T2[0] = T1[0] + 1` and `N2 = 1`, then the random string is equal to `S2`. Adding more characters to `S2` only make `S2` greater than the random string. So, `L` must be greater than or equal to `K + 1`.

To summarize, we have:

- For `N1 = 0` and `N2 = 0`, `L = K`.
- For `N1 > 0` and `N2 > 0`, `L > K`.
- For `N1 = 0` and `N2 > 0`, `L = [K L2]` if `T2 = 00...0`, otherwise `L >= K`.

Given the above, we generate a random value `L` for `S`.

**[Step 2]** We compute the smallest string `S1L` of length `L` that is greater than or equal to `S1`. If `L >= L1`, then `S1L` is `S1` appended with enough `C1` characters to make its length equal to `L`. For example, if `S1` is `23906` and `L` is `8`, `S1L = 23906000`. On the other hand, if `L < L1`, we truncate `S1` to length `L` and add `1` as explained above. For example, if `S1` is `23906` and `L` is `3`, `S1L = 240`.

**[Step 3]** We compute the largest string `S2L` of length `L` that is less than or equal to `S2`. If `L > L2`, then `S2L` is `S2` minus `1` (as explained above) appended with enough `C2` characters to make its length equal to `L`. For example, if `S2` is `23906` and `L` is `8`, `S2L = 23905999`. On the other hand, if `L < L2`, we truncate `S2` to length `L`. For example, if `S2` is `23906` and `L` is `3`, `S2L = 239`.

**[Step 4]** Now that we have both the smallest and largest strings of length `L` that fall in the range `[S1 S2]`, it is easy to generate a random string of length `L` in the same range. We simply set `S[i]` to a random character value in the range `[S1L[i] S2L[i]]` for every `i` from `0` to `L – 1`.

Here is the C code that implements the solution.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "assert.h"
#include "time.h"

/* Generate a random string in inclusive range [S1 S2] of maximum length M. */
/* S1, S2, and the returned random string have their characters in the range [C1 C2]. */
/* Returns NULL if no string of maximum length M exists in [S1 S2]. */
char * randstr(char * S1, char * S2, int M, int C1, int C2)
{
    /* Validate inputs. */
    if (S1 == NULL || S2 == NULL || *S1 == 0 || *S2 == 0) return NULL;
    if (strcmp(S1, S2) > 0) return NULL;
    if (C1 > C2) return NULL;

    /* Lengths of input strings. */
    int L1 = strlen(S1);
    int L2 = strlen(S2);

    /* Length of longest common starting sequence of S1 and S2. */
    int K = 0;
    for (; K < L1 && K < L2 && S1[K] == S2[K]; K++);

    /* Generate length of random string S. */
    int L;

    int N1 = L1 - K;
    int N2 = L2 - K;

    if (N1 == 0 && N2 == 0)
    {
        /* L = K */
        if (M < K) return NULL;
        L = K;
    }
    else if (N1 > 0 && N2 > 0)
    {
        /* L = [K + 1 M] */
        if (M < K + 1) return NULL;
        L = (rand() % (M - (K + 1) + 1)) + K + 1;
    }
    else if (N1 == 0 && N2 > 0)
    {
        char * T2 = S2 + K;
        while (*T2 > 0 && *T2 == C1)
            T2++;

        if (*T2 == 0) /* T2 = C1 + C1 + ... + C1 */
        {
            /* L = [K L2] */
            if (M < K) return NULL;
            if (M < L2)
                L = (rand() % (M - K + 1)) + K;
            else
                L = (rand() % (L2 - K + 1)) + K;
        }
        else
        {
            /* L >= K */
            if (M < K) return NULL;
            L = (rand() % (M - K + 1)) + K;
        }
    }

    /* Compute smallest string S1L of length L that is greater than S1. */
    char * S1L = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (L + 1));
    S1L[L] = 0;
    if (L >= L1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < L1; S1L[i] = S1[i++]);   /* Copy S1 into S1L. */
        for (int i = L1; i < L; S1L[i++] = C1);      /* Append C1 characters. */
    }
    else /* L < L1 */
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < L; S1L[i] = S1[i++]);    /* Set S1L to S1 truncated to length L. */
        for (int i = L - 1; i >= 0; i--)             /* Increment S1L. */
        {
            if (S1L[i] < C2)
            {
                S1L[i]++;
                break;
            }
            else
                S1L[i] = C1;
        }
    }

    /* Compute largest string S2L of length L that is less than S2. */
    char * S2L = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (L + 1));
    S2L[L] = 0;
    if (L > L2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < L2; S2L[i] = S2[i++]);    /* Copy S2 into S2L. */
        for (int i = L2; i < L; S2L[i++] = C2);       /* Append C2 characters. */
        for (int i = L2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)             /* Decrement copy of S2. */
        {
            if (S2L[i] > C1)
            {
                S2L[i]--;
                break;
            }
            else
                S2L[i] = C2;
        }
    }
    else /* L < L2 */
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < L; S2L[i] = S2[i++]);     /* Set S2L to S2 truncated to length L. */
    }

    /* Generate random string S of length L in range [S1L S2L]. */
    char * S = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (L + 1));
    S[L] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        S[i] = (rand() % (S2L[i] - S1L[i] + 1)) + S1L[i];

    free(S1L);
    free(S2L);

    return S;
}

/* Generate a random string in exclusive range (S1 S2) of maximum length M. */
/* S1, S2, and the returned random string have their characters in the range [C1 C2]. */
/* Returns NULL if no string of maximum length M exists in (S1 S2). */
char * randstrx(char * S1, char * S2, int M, int C1, int C2)
{
    /* If S1 + 1 >= S2, then no random string exists in (S1 S2). */
    int L1 = strlen(S1);
    char * S = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (L1 + 1));
    strcpy(S, S1);
    for (int i = L1 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (S[i] < C2)
        {
            S[i] += 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(S, S2) >= 0)
    {
        free(S);
        return NULL;
    }

    do
    {
        free(S);
        S = randstr(S1, S2, M, C1, C2);
    }
    while (strcmp(S, S1) == 0 || strcmp(S, S2) == 0);

    return S;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); // initialisation de rand

    char * s;

    /* N1 == 0, N2 == 0, K == 1 */
    s = randstr("0", "0", 10, '0', '9');
    assert(strcmp(s, "0") == 0);

    /* N1 == 0, N2 == 0, K == 4 */
    s = randstr("1210", "1210", 10, '0', '9');
    assert(strcmp(s, "1210") == 0);

    /* N1 == 0, N2 == 1, K == 3, T2 == 0 */
    s = randstr("121", "1210", 3, '0', '9');
    assert(strcmp(s, "121") == 0);

    /* N1 == 0, N2 == 1, K == 3, T2 == 0 */
    s = randstr("121", "1210", 4, '0', '9');
    assert(strcmp(s, "121") == 0 || strcmp(s, "1210") == 0);

    /* N1 == 1, N2 == 1, K == 3, T2 != 0 */
    s = randstr("1210", "1211", 4, '0', '9');
    assert(strcmp(s, "1210") == 0 || strcmp(s, "1211") == 0);

    /* N1 == 1, N2 == 1, K == 3, T2 != 0 */
    s = randstr("1210", "1211", 5, '0', '9');
    assert(strcmp(s, "1210") >= 0 || strcmp(s, "1211") <= 0);

    /* N1 == 4, N2 == 1, K == 0, T2 != 0 */
    s = randstr("0004", "1", 25, '0', '9');
    assert(strcmp(s, "0004") >= 0 || strcmp(s, "1") <= 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do realize that this *isn't* a bounty question, right? This is a lot of content.